# Data Annotation table columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-6

```
public partial class Employee
{     
    public int Emp_Id { get; set; }
    public string Emp_Name { get; set; }
    public string Emp_City { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Emp_Age { get; set; }
}
```

This is generated class for table `Employee` using EF. I want `Emp_Name` change to `EmpName` in application without changing table structure. But using below changes using data annotation `dbEntity.Set<Employee>().ToList();`  getting exception

> "The entity type Employee is not part of the model for the current
>   context."
>
> System.InvalidOperationException.

How can solve this

```
public partial class Employee
{ 
    public int Emp_Id { get; set; }
    [Column("Emp_Name")]
    public string EmpName { get; set; }
    public string Emp_City { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Emp_Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When Adding Data Annotation Attribute it's throwing Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26518118/when-adding-data-annotation-attribute-its-throwing-exception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change the column's name. You can easily use [`[Display]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayattribute.name(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`[DisplayName]`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.displaynameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) attribute like this:

Add `using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;` to your using directives first then:

```
[Display(Name = "EmpName")]
public string Emp_Name { get; set; }
```

Or:

```
[DisplayName("EmpName")]
public string Emp_Name { get; set; }
```

Comment: Want to property name as `EmpName ` and use it everywhere in the project,

Comment: @safeenarasak in every view that you use `Emp_Name` it shows it as `EmpName`. So you will get your desired result.

Comment: `  IEnumerable<Employee> ds =   return dbEntity.Set<Employee>().ToList();
            foreach (var x in ds)
            {
                string name = x.Emp_Name.ToString();
            }` here I want ` string name = x.EmpName.ToString();`

Comment: @S.Akbari The `Display` attribute is used for UI and the OP wants to rename the property so it can be used within code.

Comment: @safeenarasak The `Display` attribute is affected in Views only.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of:

> The entity type `Employee` is not part of the model for the current
>   context.

Exception is that `dbcontext` is not aware of `Employee` type you need to register it with `dbContext`

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Employee> Employees {get; set;}
}
```

`MyDbContext` is your `dbContext` class and you need to define `dbset` of type `employee` in that override the `OnModelCreating` method of `DbContext` in your `context` like below:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().ToTable("Employee");
}
```

If you are changing the name for display purpose then you can use `Display` Or `DisplayName` as [S.Akbari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2946329/s-akbari) mentioned in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44403677/1505865).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using Database First approach. Do the following to change the property name without changing the column name:

1. Just double click your `.edmx` file and it will show the tables.
2. Find your table, `right click the column name > Rename`
3. Give it a new name of your choice

It will keep this name and if you update your EDMX, it will still keep it. However, if you delete the EDMX and regenerate it, then you would need to do the renaming again.